# What to do with "WARN TaskSetManager: Stage contains a task of very large size"?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-1.6

I use spark 1.6.1.

My spark application reads more than 10000 parquet files stored in s3.

```
val df = sqlContext.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet(myPaths: _*)
```

`myPaths` is an `Array[String]` that contains the paths of the 10000 parquet files. Each path is like this `s3n://bucketname/blahblah.parquet`

Spark warns message like below.

> WARN TaskSetManager: Stage  4 contains a task of very large size
>   (108KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100KB.

Spark has managed to run and finish the job anyway but I guess this can slow down spark processing job.

Does anybody has a good suggestion about this problem?

Comment: Please share your code, currently we have to less information to help

Comment: Hi! I don't understand. Even in small dataset, the smallest partitions is often far bigger than 100KB, ofter ~32Mo. So how could repartitioning could help?

Comment: See https://github.com/jaceklaskowski/mastering-apache-spark-book/blob/master/spark-TaskSetManager.adoc

Answer (score 16):

The issue is that your dataset is not evenly distributed across partitions and hence some partitions have more data than others (and so some tasks compute larger results).

By default Spark SQL assumes 200 partitions using `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` property (see [Other Configuration Options](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#other-configuration-options)):

> **spark.sql.shuffle.partitions** (default: 200) Configures the number of partitions to use when shuffling data for joins or aggregations.

A solution is to `coalesce` or `repartition` your Dataset after you've read parquet files (and before executing an action).

Use `explain` or web UI to review execution plans.

---

The warning gives you a hint to optimize your query so the more effective result fetch is used (see [TaskSetManager](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/TaskSetManager.scala#L482-L488)).

With the warning TaskScheduler (that runs on the driver) will fetch the result values using the less effective approach `IndirectTaskResult` (as you can see in [the code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/TaskResultGetter.scala#L57-L125)).