# Pyspark - Write DF into partitions efficiently

Tags: java, apache-spark, memory-management, pyspark, partition-by

I am trying to write a spark dataframe to hdfs using partition by.

But it is throwing java heap space error.

Below is the cluster configuration and my spark configuration.

**Cluster Configuration:**

```
5 nodes
No of cores/node: 32 cores
RAM/Node: 252GB
```

**Spark Configuration:**

```
spark.driver.memory = 50g
spark.executor.cores = 10
spark.executor.memory = 40g
```

df_final is created by reading an avro file and doing some transformations (quite simple transformations like column split and adding new columns with default values)

The size of the source file is around 15M

```
df_final.count() = 361016
```

I am facing java heap space error while writing the final df to hdfs:

```
df_final.write.partitionBy("col A", "col B", "col C", "col D").mode("append").format("orc").save("output")
```

I even tried to use spark dynamic configuration:

```
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled = 'true'
spark.shuffle.service.enabled = 'true'
```

Still having java heap space error.

I even tried to write the df without partitions but it still fails with java heap space error or GC overhead error.

This is the exact stage at which i am having java heap space error:

```
WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 30 contains a task of very large size (16648KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB
```

How can I fine tune my spark configuration to avoid this java head space issue??

Comment: Can you share the error logs ? Also check your ui for data skews

Comment: i wont be able to share u the error logs, however i do know that one of the partition column has a lot of null values. so there might be a chance for data skews. let me put a default value for all null records

Comment: if you have null records,you can drop them ,if not required and see the differences.

Comment: i think i need the null records also. But i tried to put a default value "Null" for those column values having null, to the partition column (col C) . Still having java heap space. This is the exact error: WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 30 contains a task of very large size (16648KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB

Comment: I updated the post with the stage at which error occurs

Comment: I think this post answers your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996615/what-to-do-with-warn-tasksetmanager-stage-contains-a-task-of-very-large-size

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208384/discussion-between-blackfury-and-tarun).